# Karate - Use a variable in a schema validation

Tags: karate

I'd like to check the schema of my response using a regex
The response must start with the content of my variable 'myVar' and end with anything

Example:

```
Scenario: Schema with variable
   * def myVar = 'https://google.com'
   Given path 'path'
   When method Get
   And match response == 
   """
   {
      "id": "#uuid",
      "name": "#string",
      "url": "#regex ^#(myVar).*"
   }
   """
```

But it seems that the contents of my variable are not being retrieved correctly

its possible to use concatenation?

```
   "url": "#regex ^" + #(myVar) + ".*"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this instead:

```
* def response = { url: 'foobar' }
* def myVar = 'foo'
* def isValidUrl = function(x){ return x.startsWith(myVar) }
* match response == { url: '#? isValidUrl(_)' }
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#self-validation-expressions

You can't use variables in a `#regex`.